# How do I upgrade my Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 to Enterprise 2017?

Tags: visual-studio

I don't see any notifications for it or an uption to update. I need to use the V141 tools.

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 is a different product from Visual Studio 2015. If you need Visual Studio 2017, you need to get a license for it (or use the free Community edition). There is no option to upgrade Visual Studio 2015 to Visual Studio 2017, but you can install both versions side-by-side on the same machine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

uninstall VS 2015, install VS 2017

Comment: Why are you proposing to uninstall Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: because he wants a upgrade, not a parallel installation.

Comment: There is no upgrade path. Those are different products. And while there are no issues involved when installing those products side-by-side, arbitrarily uninstalling a product does not appear to be helpful in any way.